# Restrict handlebars-partials for spedific pages

Tags: node.js, web-development-server, express-handlebars, hbs, nodejs-express-server

How to restrict handlebars-partials while rendering specific pages ?

```
                   Or
```

How to enable handlebars-partials while rendering specific pages only ?

Comment: Muneeb you have to pass some variables with your controller when you render those pages and you can set if block on the frontend ( hbs side ) if those variables are true at that time pass this partials page.

Comment: Ex :- Send this when you render page path: "/user",   ```<% if (path === /user ){ %>```
      Your Logic
```<%}%>```  This EJS syntax you follow may Hbs Syntax

Comment: Have to clear quetion